# Image scaling in Fabric.js on IPad

Tags: ipad, fabricjs

Fabric.js Image object on IPad scales wrong.

Fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/FfUz7/20/
```

IPad air OS 7:

```
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByFQg7Hn-cFVaUhLem1LWWR4bFk/edit
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is [known iOS issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1013).

Comment: I've got image squash ratio by detectVerticalSquash function from [here](https://github.com/stomita/ios-imagefile-megapixel/blob/master/src/megapix-image.js) and now cant understand how to "stretch" image by this ratio (increase image height without increasing height of FabricJS Object). Is this possible by means of FabricJS? Thanks a lot!